# Java Failure: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied on Banana Pi

Tags: java, socketexception

I'm running into the following error trying to run `ScanToNag` (http://www.vanheusden.com/java/ScanToNag/) from a Banana Pi running Debian.

Failure: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

I've tried `java 6, 7` and even oracle version 8 and encountering the same problem.

I'm running as root. `SELinux` is not on, `iptables` and `ufw` are not on. Tried Bananian as well.

I also tried

`-Dsocket.permit_connect=true and -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

but both aren't helping.

I suspect it has something to do with `ARM` support, but not sure how to check...any ideas?

Update: 
Here is the tail end of the output from verbose running in version 7

```
    Scanning 10.24.24.0 to 10.24.24.255
   10.24.24.0
[Loaded Probe from file:/usr/local/aces/adcp/lib/ScanToNag-0.2.jar]
[Loaded Prober from file:/usr/local/aces/adcp/lib/ScanToNag-0.2.jar]
[Loaded java.io.InterruptedIOException from /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.net.SocketTimeoutException from /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.net.SocketAddress from /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.net.InetSocketAddress from /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.net.SocketException from /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf/jre/lib/rt.jar]
Failure: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

Update: Apparently the problem is related to running as the root user. By simply adding a user to the system and running under that user everything is working.

Comment: Does your exception include a line number? Java usually doesn't care if you're running ARM, it is made to be platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to running java as the root user. After changing to a regular user I'm now able to run this which is a good enough solution for me.